# How to make ios keyboard with two type of return button?

Tags: ios, swift

My app has a text field that accepts a number. After the user fills the number, I want my user to have two choice of return buttons. One return to run function A, and one return to run function B. They also have to hold down the return button for 2 seconds to make it work.

Does anyone know how to do this? Please answer in `Swift`.

Comment: better to provide buttons inside UI

Answer (score 0):

Configure and add buttons to the text field's `inputAccessoryView`; this view, including its subviews (the buttons), will appear at the top of the keyboard.